# Drawing a highlight over selected ability

Tags: game-maker

(I am new to gamemaker)

In gamemaker, I'm not sure what a good way of drawing a highlight sprite over a specific area on my ability bar, when my "mode" variable is in a certain position. For example, when I press the key 1, my mode variable becomes 1, which should highlight the top right hand corner of my screen, (780,0) but when I press the key 2, my mode variable becomes 2, and the first highlight at (780,0) gets erased and another highlight gets placed at (780,80).

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Are you trying to draw several highlights on the screen, or only one per time is needed? Also, how big is your viewport?

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear, as I'm not sure whether this is about drawing a sprite, or modifying one somehow with an effect.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you should be using the following piece of code inside a `draw` event:

```
draw_set_rectangle(780, (variable * size_square), 780 + size_square,
        (variable * size_square) + size_square, 1)
```

.. where `variable` is the index of the ability to be highlighted.

---

You can change the highlight color with this:

```
draw_set_color(c_red)
```

.. where `c_red` is nothing more than `c_anyBasicColor`, `c_blue`, `c_green`, etc.

---

You should either list `variable` as a *global variable* by writing `global.variable` every time, which is a general programming *no-no*, or put your code inside an object that hosts `variable`.